# Passing the same data over different views in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, controller

I have for example this code in my HomeController:

```
    public function index() {


    $comments = Comment::get_recent();
    $top = User::get_top_uploaders()->get();
    $top_something = User::get_top_something_uploaders()->get();
    $data = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(6);

    return View::make('index')  ->with('data', $data)
                                ->with('comments', $comments)
                                ->with('top', $top)
                                ->with('top_something', $top_something);

}
```

It works great, but I need to make another couple of view with the same data not only for index but also for other pages like `comments()`, `post()`... 
How to make this in HomeController that I don't need to make it copy and paste those variables in every controller?

Comment: Maybe check out [view composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers). They are useful to pass data to a view (or multiple views), just as long as the way of generating the data doesn't depend on the controller or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your data using share method:

```
// for single controller:
class SomeController extends BaseController {
  public function __construct()
  {
    $data = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(6);
    View::share('data', $data);
  } 
}
```

For all controllers you can put this code in BaseController's constructor

Answer (score 2):

If the data is displayed using the same HTML each time you could put that piece of HTML into a partial and then use a View Composer.

Create a view and call it whatever you want and put in your HTML for the data.

In templates that need that partial include it `@include('your.partial')`

In either app/routes.php or even better app/composers.php (don't forget to autoload it)

```
View::Composer('your.partial', function($view)
{
    $data = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(6);
    $view->with('data', $data);
});
```

Now whenever that partial is included in one of your templates it will have access to your data