# How to reuse a component in Laravel WITH its controller functionality

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

## What I have done

I have a list of stuff fetched from my database and displayed in a list. Let's call it "**stuff-list**". The router displays this list when I 'get' `/stufflist`. The connected controller fetches the data and passes it to the template.

## What I want to do

I want to display this list on other pages (in my case: a **dashboard**) where the list is only a component beside others.

What is the best-practice? When I type `/dashboard` I, of course, get an error because the **stuff-list** I am including there does not have the data from it's controller.

I don't want to implement the fetching of the data in every controller for every template I use the **stuff-list** in. Do I have to implement kind of a repository and use this in every controller for every template including the **stuff-list**? Or is there any better way?

What I wish to do is to create a component displaying the stuff and a controller that is bound to that component. Everytime I include this component (displaying the stuff) on any page it sould be included with all the logic behind it.

How do I do this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe this helps you a bit.  
[Passing the same data over different views in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835002/passing-the-same-data-over-different-views-in-laravel?answertab=votes#tab-top)  or this one  
[How can I share data from a different controller in a laravel view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470130/how-can-i-share-data-from-a-different-controller-in-a-laravel-view?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Or use the Method @haakym used with `@inject` in your blade-template.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered **[Service Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#service-injection)**? If you're using blade templating then you can take advantage of it.

Let's say your interaction with the DB to get the stuff-list is in a method in a model or in a dedicated query class you can do something like this in your blade template:

```
@inject('stuffList', 'App\Queries\StuffList')

<div>
    Monthly Revenue: {{ $stuffList->get() }}.
</div>
```

You can then extract the part where it's used into a partial and pull that into a master template or any blade file using [`@include` see: Including sub views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures)

Comment: Maybe put the comment on the question?